# Javascript Readmore function works only on first php object but does not apply to subsequent objects

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to implement Readmore/readless functionality for a Laravel feed page that returns many objects from DB. The problem is my readmore code only works for the first object but doesn't work on subsequent objects. It's kind of a Facebook feed page where you can view posts from friends and then click the "Readmore" button to expand a comment or a note. That's precisely what I'm trying to implement. My "Readmore" code works only for the first object. I'd like some help with making the "Readmore" button apply to all objects from the DB.

Below is my code

```
**HTML**
    <div class="container row">

        @forelse ($counters as $key => $counter)

       <div>
           <h6>Title</h6>
           <p>{{ $counter->title }}</p>
       </div>
                     
       <div>
           <h6>Address</h6> 
           <p>{{ $counter->address }}</p>
       </div><span id="dots"></span><span id="moretext">

       <div>
           <h6>Email</h6>
           <p>{{ $counter->email }}</p>
       </div>
                     
       <div>
           <h6>Contact no.</h6> 
           <p>{{ $counter->contact }}</p>
       </div>

       </span><button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

@empty 
  No information published yet.
@endforelse 

</div>


**CSS**

  <style>
      #moretext {display: none;}
  </style>


**JS**
<script>
   function myFunction() {
        var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
        var moreText = document.getElementById("moretext");
        var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
      moreText.style.display = "none";
  } 
else 
{
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` will return only first matching element.
you can try some dynamic id = dots-`$counter->id` 
and pass it `onClick` function

Comment: Also when asking client side questions, please post a [mcve] using ONLY HTML, CSS and JS, without any PHP if it is irrelevant as it is here

Comment: @SyedQasimAhmed, pls can you show a clearer code? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ids need to be unique`

This is the code you are looking for

```html
<div class="container row">

        
        @foreach ($counters as $key => $counter)
       <div>
           <h6>Title</h6>
           <p>{{ $counter->title }}</p>
       </div>
                     
       <div>
           <h6>Address</h6> 
           <p>{{ $counter->address }}</p>
       </div><span id="dots-<?php echo $key; ?>"></span><span id="moretext-<?php echo $key; ?>">

       <div>
           <h6>Email</h6>
           <p>{{ $counter->email }}</p>
       </div>
                     
       <div>
           <h6>Contact no.</h6> 
           <p>{{ $counter->contact }}</p>
       </div>

       </span><button onclick="myFunction(this.id)" data-value="myBtn-<?php echo $key; ?>" id="myBtn-<?php echo $key; ?>">Read more</button>

@empty 
  No information published yet.
@endforeach

</div>



  <style>
      #moretext {display: none;}
  </style>


<script>
   var dataLength = '<?php echo sizeof($counters); ?>';
   for(var i=0; i<dataLength; i++){
       document.getElementById("moretext-"+i).style.display = 'none';
   }
   
   function myFunction(clicked_id) {
        var dataLength = '<?php echo sizeof($counters); ?>';
        //alert(dataLength);
        var dots = [];
        var moreText = [];
        var btnText = [];
        //alert(clicked_id);
        
        for(var i=0; i<dataLength; i++){
            dots.push(document.getElementById("dots-"+i));
            moreText.push(document.getElementById("moretext-"+i));
            btnText.push(document.getElementById("myBtn-"+i));
            
        if(document.getElementById("myBtn-"+i).getAttribute("data-value") == clicked_id){   
            if (dots[i].style.display === "none") {
                    dots[i].style.display = "inline";
                    btnText[i].innerHTML = "Read more"; 
                    moreText[i].style.display = "none";
                } 
            else 
            {
                dots[i].style.display = "none";
                btnText[i].innerHTML = "Read less"; 
                moreText[i].style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
            
        }
        

  
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique. Use a class.

Your HTML is invalid. A span cannot contain a div. Make it a div and wrap your content and you can use delegation like this

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches(".readMore")) return ; // not a button
  const parent = tgt.closest(".item");
  const dots = parent.querySelector(".dots");
  const moreText = parent.querySelector(".moretext");
  dots.hidden = !dots.hidden;
  moreText.hidden = !moreText.hidden;
  tgt.textContent = dots.hidden ? "Read less" : "Read more";
})
```

```css
.dots:after { content: "…" }
```

```html
<div class="container row">
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h6>Title</h6>
      <p>Title 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Address</h6>
      <p>Address 1</p>
    </div><span class="dots"></span>
    <div class="moretext" hidden>
      <div>
        <h6>Email</h6>
        <p>Email 1</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6>Contact no.</h6>
        <p>Contact 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="readMore">Read more</button>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h6>Title</h6>
      <p>Title 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Address</h6>
      <p>Address 2</p>
    </div><span class="dots"></span>
    <div class="moretext" hidden>
      <div>
        <h6>Email</h6>
        <p>Email 2</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6>Contact no.</h6>
        <p>Contact 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="readMore">Read more</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Your code:

```html
<div class="container row">
  @forelse ($counters as $key => $counter)
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <h6>Title</h6>
      <p>{{ $counter->title }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Address</h6>
      <p>{{ $counter->address }}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="dots"></span>
    <div class="moretext" hidden>
      <div>
        <h6>Email</h6>
        <p>{{ $counter->email }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6>Contact no.</h6>
        <p>{{ $counter->contact }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="readMore">Read more</button>
  </div>
  @empty No information published yet. 
  @endforelse
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I'm still facing the same problem. Are you aware data displayed comes from various users? I implemented your code, but only the first object gets truncated and the rest do not.

Comment: `<span class+"dots"></span>`  You have a plus sign after "class."  `<div class="moretext: hidden">` There's a colon sign after "moretext" which isn't in your supposed solution. Can you please clarify

Comment: Typos. `<div class="item"><div><h6>Title</h6><p></p></div><div><h6>Address</h6></div><span class="dots"></span><div class="moretext" hidden"><div><h6>Contact</h6><p></p></div><div><h6>Email</h6><p></p></div></div><button></button></div>`

Comment: @ObiKolin I added the template like I expect it to be. Let me know

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, the readmore button only works for the first object from the database. Subsequent readmore doesn't respond when clicked. I used your template.

Comment: @ObiKolin Did you change id to class and remove the onclick? `<button class="myBtn">Read more</button>`